# What computer would be fastest for Mathematica Home Edition?

Tags: performance-tuning, hardware

I am planning the purchase of a new computer for use with Mathematica Home Edition, which is limited, as far as I understand, to two simultaneous kernels. Can anyone recommend particular hardware?

Comment: Related: [Best Mac for Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165908/best-mac-for-mathematica) and [Which processor and graphics card to use for my Mathematica license](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159411/which-processor-and-graphics-card-to-use-for-my-mathematica-license)

Comment: Common recommendations are to get a lot of RAM and SSD.

Comment: I agree with comment above! RAM and drive size is a definite consideration issue.  I recently purchased a new MacBook Pro 15" with 16 MB RAM and 1 TB SSD.  I regularly perform analysis on time based data files that are hundreds of mega bytes in size.  This MacBook Pro is better than my work desktop system.  The biggest issue for me is RAM.  I need to get a lot data in memory where I can perform the Mathematica operations. I say go with as much RAM, drive, and processor as your wallet will allow.  Mathematica runs great on MacOS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is right, you can run only two Mathematica kernels at once in the Home Edition. But whether this is an actual limitation (and whether you should prefer a CPU with high single-core throughput) depends on what you are about to do with *Mathematica*.

I can only speak for my personal scope of application which is numerics. Here I seldomly find the `Parallel`-framework helpful, as `Compile`d code with options `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` and `Parallelization -> True` usually scales much better than `Parallel` and friends. Such parallelized code is sped up by Intel MKL (and OpenMP?) outside of the *Mathematica* kernel. Even better is to use vectorized code for linear algebra; such is accelerated also by Intel MKL and such low level libraries as BLAS. The hardware ressources used are also independent of the number of *Mathematica* kernels.
So, for numerical computations, you may enjoy mostly all the benefits of a fat multi core CPU, even with the Home Edition.

Things might be different for vast symbolic computations, though, or when you are forced to run slow built-in functions that are not parallelized themselves and that you cannot reimplement yourselves more efficiently.

If you are interested in neural network facilities, you might prefer NVidia graphics cards over those by AMD since only CUDA, not OpenCL is supported. Anyways, most algorithms in *Mathematica* are not optimized for GPUs, so apart from the very localized application of neural networks, also the particular choice of GPU does not matter much.

In think the only general advice that one can give is: Having lots of memory is *always* a good idea and does not harm in any case. Apart from that, I doubt that it is a good idea to build your new machine depending on your *Mathematica* license.

#### Addendum

A propos Intel MKL: I really hate to say this (and it might cost me further downvotes), but as far as numerics in *Mathematica* are considered, one should keep in mind that Intel CPUs *might* be preferable over AMD CPUs just because Intel MKL is optimized for Intel hardware (and rumor has it that AMD processors are nerfed in MKL). I cannot quantify the difference in performance/price ratio, though; I just wanted to make you aware of that.

Comment: Might you elaborate on what make Mma's `Parallel` frameowrk "almost useless" in your view?

Comment: I do use the parallel tools a lot. I would not call them useless at all. It is true that parallelizing tight inner loops will often not provide much speedup (sometimes it will though), but parallelization is quite useful for running a slow function many times (e.g. batch processing).

Comment: @Szabolcs "parallelization is quite useful for running a slow function many times" You are definitely more an expert in `Parallel` than me. I have the tendency not to use slow functions, i.e. to look for alternatives or to rewrite them when they get crucial for my work. In my personal field of interest, I am capable of doing that, but I also understand that the generic user does not have the time and background knowledge to do so. But maybe you agree in the point that the generic user will also struggle quite a lot with `Parallel`.

Comment: @Alan Okay, I admit, that was a bit opinionated. I rephrased the statement and also detailed out my argumentation.

Comment: "I have the tendency not to use slow functions".  What I meant was that a loop (Table, Map) is worth parallelizing if each iteration takes a noticeable time.  In these cases, it can provide a significant speedup. If each iteration takes 10^-6 seconds, then it won't.  If you have a big enough problem, then it will always take a while to run. People run highly optimized C programs for days on HPC clusters :-)

Comment: E.g. last time I needed to do some image processing. Just a PeronaMalikFilter will often take a noticeable amount of time. I had hundreds of images.  Parallelization was a huge help.  But only the outermost loop was parallelized (i.e. batch-process all images).